# Sign of $\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-A^*A}B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, trace

Let $V$ be a complex vector space and $A,B\in \operatorname{End}(V)$. Given that $\operatorname{Tr}(B)<0$, can we know the sign of
$$\operatorname{Tr}(e^{-A^*A}B)$$
where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$?

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that $(-A^*A)$ may be diagonalizable ?

Comment: When $t\ge0,\,A=\pmatrix{\sqrt{t}\\ &0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{-2\\ &1}$, the trace of $e^{-A^\ast A}B$ is $1-2e^{-t}$, whose sign is not constant.

Comment: @user1551 what about if $B$ has only negative eigenvalues?

Comment: @BinAcker Replace the $B$ above by $\pmatrix{-2&-\frac{9}{4}\\ 1&1}$.